# Power BI Report Builder =Today() function in datetime parameter causing it to gray out

Tags: parameters, powerbi, reportbuilder

I was hoping someone could point me in the right direction. I am using Power BI Report Builder. I have a start date and end date parameter. My start data parameter is set to Data Type: Date/Time. Available values is set to None.

I want to set a default start date. For example, Today - 30 days. So, as a test, I tried to set the start date to today by entering =Today() as a function in the default value.

When I run the report, the start date parameter is grayed out. I am able to add a value like 2023.12.01 into the default value of the parameter and it works fine.

Any idea why =Today() would cause the parameter to gray out? Thanks in advance for any tips or clues that may solve this issue.

I have tried =Now() and =Today(). Both caused the parameter to gray out.

The issue seems to relate to the Dataset Query Parameter. (see link 4 below) I assume this because if I create a new report and pass =True() to a Date/Time parameter on my machine, it works fine.

I have tried to format the default parameter value to short date and I also tried to change the formatting in various ways in the Dataset Query Parameter formula with no luck.

Also, my query works fine if I do not set defaults on the start date and end date parameters. So, the issue is not related to the query design.

[image: Parameter Type]

[image: Parameter Function]

[image: Start Date Parameter grayed out]

[image: Dataset Query Parameter Function]

Answer (score 0):

Simply because the function you need to use in the expression is Today :

[image]

[image]

Result :

[image]